# Unbound split horizon DNS for NextDNS routing per VLAN

Tags: configuration, dns, pfsense, unbound

I'm running Unbound version 1.13.2 (the most recent version available on PFSense). I'm trying to do some source based routing of my DNS traffic. I use NextDNS and have set up two profiles, one for VLANA and one for VLANB with different rules. I want to conditionally forward the request based on the VLAN the requests come in on. I've read I can do this using "views" and "access-control-view" tags. So, I've come up with the following configuration, which passes the Unbound config check just fine, and Unbound will start and answer queries, but all queries are forward to the LAST "view" in the configuration no matter what I do. Any help is appreciated...

```
#https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/index.html

server:

    access-control-view: 10.0.5.0/24 vlana
    access-control-view: 10.0.6.0/24 vlanb

    log-replies: yes
    log-tag-queryreply: yes
    log-local-actions: yes
    log-servfail: yes

    private-domain: "plex.direct"
    
    forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-tls-upstream: yes
        forward-addr: 45.90.28.0#987654.dns.nextdns.io
        forward-addr: 45.90.30.0#987654.dns.nextdns.io
        
view:
    name: "vlana"
    view-first: no
    forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-tls-upstream: yes
        forward-addr: 45.90.28.0#123456.dns.nextdns.io
        forward-addr: 45.90.30.0#123456.dns.nextdns.io
        
view:
    name: "vlanb"
    view-first: no
    forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-tls-upstream: yes
        forward-addr: 45.90.28.0#789101.dns.nextdns.io
        forward-addr: 45.90.30.0#789101.dns.nextdns.io
```